# Any apps to integrate calendar and contacts?

Tags: contacts, calendars

Have WP 7.5.  Not happy with contact-to-calendar integration.  I want to add a contact, with their address and phone, then be able to send the contact to the calendar for a meeting.

As a business function, I LIKE the map integration once the address is entered into the calendar.  Right now, I have to double enter the address to use..

Are there any third party apps that integrate both?

Google might do this, but they seem to need e-email as a common link.  I would like to be able to select the name from my contact list, also

Comment: I add contacts to a meeting from within the calendar, they get an email when I do this.

Comment: Yeah, @WayneInYak, me too. This is the standard behavior that requires me to enter the address twice, because the calendar and the contact book are not integrated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not integrated. When I'm in the calendar and go to add someone I see all my contacts listed. I just have to select which one. No entering addresses twice.

Comment: The calendar primary entry screen has subject and location.  One level down is attendees.  Adding an attendee doesn't set the meeting location, that has to be (re)entered. Also, contacts from phone list don't show up, only email contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, this is not possible using the native calendar app on Windows Phone 7 or even Windows Phone 8 for that matter. I have looked at some of the other calendar solutions in the Windows Phone Marketplace and none of the apps (that I tried) allowed me to do what you are looking to do.

Had you been on a Windows Phone 8 device, I would have recommended adding a feature suggestion to the official [Windows Phone User Voice](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com) site but it is highly unlikely that Windows Phone 7 will get any feature updates beyond 7.8.

The only other thing that you could possibly do is to check in on some [calendar apps in the Windows Phone Marketplace](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/search?q=calendar). Even in this case though, I wouldn't be too hopeful as the feature you are looking for is very specific and many of the newer apps are built for Windows Phone 8 only.